# Почему не отображаются стили REACT JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Прописал стили в отдельном компоненте, подключил его к MyModule, затем уже MyModule подключил к App.js, однако, стили не применились. Как это исправить?

MyModal.module.css:

```
.myModal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.myModalContent {
  padding: 25px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 16px;
  min-width: 250px;
}

.myModal.active {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

MyModal.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import cl from "./MyModal.module.css";

const MyModal = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className={[cl.myModal, cl.active].join("")}>
      <div className={cl.myModalContent}> {children} </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyModal;
```

App.js

```
 import React, { useState, useRef, useMemo } from "react";
import ClassCounter from "./components/ClassCounter";
import Counter from "./components/Counter";
import PostItem from "./components/PostItem";
import PostList from "./components/PostList";
import "./styles/app.css";
import MyButton from "./components/UI/button/MyButton";
import MyInput from "./components/UI/input/MyInput";
import PostForm from "./components/PostForm";
import MySelect from "./components/UI/select/MySelect";
import PostFilter from "./components/PostFilter";
import MyModal from "./components/UI/MyModal/MyModal";

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([
    { id: 1, title: "dsfsdf", body: "6464" },
    { id: 2, title: "cvbcvb", body: "978" },
    { id: 3, title: "vbnvbn", body: "333" },
  ]);

  const [filter, setFilter] = useState({ sort: "", query: "" });

  const sortedPosts = useMemo(() => {
    if (filter.sort) {
      return [...posts].sort((a, b) =>
        a[filter.sort].localeCompare(b[filter.sort])
      );
    }
    return posts;
  }, [filter, posts]);

  const sortAndSearchedPosts = useMemo(() => {
    return sortedPosts.filter((post) =>
      post.title.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filter.query.toLocaleLowerCase())
    );
  }, [filter.query, sortedPosts]);

  function createPost(newPost) {
    setPosts([...posts, newPost]);
  } 

  //Получаем пост из дочернего компонента

  function removePost(post) {
    setPosts(posts.filter((p) => p.id !== post.id));
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyModal>
        <PostForm create={createPost} />
      </MyModal>

      <hr style={{ margin: "15px 0" }} />
      <PostFilter filter={filter} setFilter={setFilter} />

      <PostList
        remove={removePost}
        posts={sortAndSearchedPosts}
        title="JS posts"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мб они  банально закэшировались?

Answer (score 3):

```
[cl.myModal, cl.active].join("")
```

В этой строке вы склеиваете два имени класса без разделителя, я бы попробовал так:

```
[cl.myModal, cl.active].join(" ")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!